# Raven db System.InvalidCastException: at at Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.TrackEntity[T]

Tags: ravendb, azure-functions

I have my code deployed as Azure function app. everything works fine at my local machine. but on Azure Function app I'm getting following exception while querying to raven db.

One or more errors occurred.System.InvalidOperationException: The query results type is 'Cat1RootRef' but you expected to get results of type 'Cat1RootRef'. If you want to return a projection, you should use .ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto() (for Query) or .SelectFields() (for DocumentQuery) before calling to .ToList(). ---> System.InvalidCastException: [A]Cqm.Models.Qrda.Cat1RootRef cannot be cast to [B]Cqm.Models.Qrda.Cat1RootRef. Type A originates from 'Cqm.Models, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1dad2e84fc016e57' in the context 'LoadNeither' in a byte array. Type B originates from 'Cqm.Models, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1dad2e84fc016e57' in the context 'LoadNeither' in a byte array.
   at Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.TrackEntity[T](String key, RavenJObject document, RavenJObject metadata, Boolean noTracking)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.TrackEntity[T](String key, RavenJObject document, RavenJObject metadata, Boolean noTracking)
   at Raven.Client.Document.SessionOperations.QueryOperation.Deserialize[T](RavenJObject result)
   at Raven.Client.Document.SessionOperations.QueryOperation.b__26_0[T](RavenJObject x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Raven.Client.Document.SessionOperations.QueryOperation.CompleteT
   at Raven.Client.Document.DocumentQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
   at Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryInspector`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Cqm.Services.CqmEngineService.GetPatientStream1(IDocumentSession session, DateTime from, DateTime to, List`1 providers, Int32 maxRecords)
   at Cqm.Services.CqmEngineService.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
2016-12-27T20:46:27.144 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Cqm.Services.CqmEngineService.ComputeMeasuresStreamedUpdated(StoreParams storeParams, ComputeParams computeParams)
   at Submission#0.StartEngine(CloudBlockBlob myBlob, StoreParams ravenStoreParams, TenantConfig tblTenantConfig, TenantReportResults tblTenantReportResults, TraceWriter log) in :line 94
2016-12-27T20:46:27.144

Comment: Please format your error message. Right now your question is impossible to read.

Comment: In addition, can you share some information about how you're deploying and referencing your assemblies?

Comment: I created Bin folder in my Function app directory and added my code dll's there. For raven i tried both using Nugget packages and placing dll in bin folder. code is compiling and executing fine. it's giving exception on loading some files from raven db.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have several `Cat1RootRef` types in your app, possibly loaded from multiple assemblies or assembly loaded multiple times